# PInvokeStackImbalance when calling a DLL function from C++/CLI

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll, c++-cli

While working on a C++/CLI project to wrap a native C++ DLL, I've come across a native function that takes in a `std::string`. Something like the following:

```
class NativeApi
{
public:
  ErrorCode readFile(std::string filename = "path.csv");
};
```

Inside my managed wrapper implementation I allocate a new instance of the native class and call this function:

```
ref class ManagedApi
{
private:
  NativeApi *api;
public:
  ManagedApi(): api(new NativeApi()) { }
  void Read()
  {
    api->readFile("apath.csv") // or with nothing to use default value
  }
}
```

When I run this, I get the MDA `PinvokeStackImbalance` complaining that this call has unbalanced the stack. I was surprised, since the only other time I ever got this MDA was from C# when calling conventions didn't match. I never saw this happen with C++/CLI, where presumably all the matching is done automatically by the compiler.

Has anyone ever saw this before? Googling came up empty. I've looked at the DLL signature and it looks something like:

`?readFile@NativeApi@@QAE?AW4ErrorCode@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z`

This tells me that the function is there, and takes as a sole argument a `basic_string`, which should match the standard `std::string` typedef.

No idea what could possibly have gone wrong. I can make other calls to the native API that do not involve strings perfectly fine.

Comment: Is `ManagedApi` a `ref class` (it should be if it is used by other .net code)?

Comment: Is the Native C++ DLL that you're wrapping something that you compiled? Do you have the source code to it?

Comment: @crashmstr yes it is, this was a typo, just fixed it. thanks for the headsup

Comment: @DavidYaw no, and unfortunately I also don't have access to the source code. This is the reason why I ran `dumpbin` on the DLL and the signatures seem to roughly match, although other than that I can't say much.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong with the code you are showing. Are you using the same compiler that the native DLL was compiled with?

Comment: @crashmstr this is my worry as well, I should be but I cannot be entirely sure. I do know both use MSVC. Is there any way to verify the version of the compiler by using only the .lib and/or .dll files?

Comment: It is an odd error, you are/should not be using the pinvoke marshaller when you make this call from a C++/CLI program.  Regardless, std::string is never not a problem.  It can only work correctly when your program uses the exact same compiler version with the exact same settings as the library.  You also cannot mix the debug and release builds.  You'll almost certainly will have to rebuild the library.

Comment: @HansPassant you were right, it was the Release mode that got me. I have to admit I never realized std::string raised so many problems crossing DLL boundaries, as I've always only had to deal with char* in the past. I guess this makes it clear once again why most people use C for DLL interop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that there's a difference between the definition of `std::string` that you're using vs. what was used to compile the native C++ DLL. Even if the definitions are the same, the native DLL probably isn't using the same version of the C runtime as you are, so when your DLL allocates memory for the `std::string`, the Native DLL will try to call `delete` on it (when the string is destroyed at the end of the `readFile` method), and that call to `delete` will go to a different heap than was used to allocate the object!

If you want to make this work, you'll have to use the *exact* same version of the compiler as was used on the native DLL. Note that you'll be limited to the Release build of your project, as you don't have a native DLL that was compiled with the debug runtime.

The *proper* fix to this problem is to use raw types when calling across DLL boundaries (in this case, `wchar_t*`). If you can request a change to the native DLL, I would do that. If only raw types are used, then there's no issue with using different runtimes, and everything works the way it should.

Comment: Excellent advice, I'd just like to add that apart from "raw" types, there are some that are defined by Windows for the express purpose of having a common definition regardless of language and compiler settings, so they can be freely shared across modules.  Examples include `BSTR` and `SAFEARRAY`